Access sheets from Cloud function without sharing sheets to service account
I need to read a lot of the sheets that were shared with me programmatically.
I have been able to read it on my local machine using the code below with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set.
However, when the service is deployed to Cloud Function, it can not access the file as the caller does not have permission although I have set the service account to match the one in the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS key file.
Now I don't know what permission is missing or my implementation was wrong.
const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"],
    clientOptions: {
      subject: process.env.GOOGLE_IMPERSONATE_EMAIL,
    }
  })


Firstly, you do not need a Google application credential env var and a service account key file in your cloud function. Are you sure that's the sheet access that fail? Because you are performing impersonation, and the Cloud Functions service account must be: not this one by default AND service account token creator on itself (or at project level).

Yeah, the response in postman said that the caller does not have permission. I do not set ADC and key file in Cloud Function, but I have already set runtime service account for the function

And what say the logs in Cloud Functions? Can you narrow the error? Is it when you are calling Sheet API or when you impersonate the service account (to rescope your token).

I logged the error and it shows "the caller does not have permission" error. This is the error when calling sheet API. The service account is supposed to act as a workspace user to manipulate the sheet, I have already set domain-wide to do this

You can find the solution here
I add the key file content as env var to cloud function and followed instructions in the answer below
Google OAuth using domain wide delegation and service account
